# Store and Retrieve Date in dd MMM yyyy format in MongoDB model

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a MongoDB model that contains a Date field whose type is defined as Date.now. Any date is converted to ISO date format. Inside the model the date is defined as :

```
xDate : {
  type: Date.now,
  required: true
}
```

I pass the current Date as :

```
var d = new Date();
var temp = d.toISOString();
var subStr = temp.substr(10,temp.length - 1);
var curDate = temp.replace(subStr, "T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(curDate);
```

However the date is stored as an ISO String inside the MongoDB schema. I try to query it using Mongoose using the following query:

```
X.
 find({
  xDate: curDate
 })
.exec(function(err, doc) {
 var response = {
  status : 200,
  message : doc
 };
 if (err) {
  console.log('Error');
  response.status = 500;
  response.message = err;
 } else if (!doc) {
  console.log("Documents against the date not found in database" ,curDate);
  response.status = 404;
  response.message = {
    "message" : "Documents not found for " + curDate
  };
 }
res
 .status(response.status)
 .json(response.message);
});
```

I keep getting a blank json array inspite of the data being there. Inside the table the xDate is stored as YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 0):

The date inside mongo is not stores in ISO string. If you save your model as Date.now, it will save a new Date object, not an ISO string. So one easy way of querying is to query by `new Date()` object.

Also note that your query is hard to be true, since you will have a hard time getting the exactly same date as your data is stored. I think better option for you is using `$lt` or `$gt` filters.

New query should look something like:

```
 let currDate = new Date()
 // change the date using class methods
 X.find({
     xDate: {$lt: currDate}
 }).exec...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the date using class methods"? Also you put an extra r in '$lt: curDate'.

Comment: Change the date using native Date object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and use methods of Date object. Don't use string replace methods for changing date.